# Replacing misspelled text data with the correct spelling

Tags: r

I have a set of data that is supposed to have 3 different options for the text that can go in the field but when the data was entered different spelling was used for a number of the entries. I need to replace the incorrectly spelled entries with the correct spelling.

Below is the script I have used to look at my data, find the unique values in the `mat_source` column and then how many of each value there is.

```r
glimpse(Inventory)
Rows: 4,860
Columns: 5
asset_ID   <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 3…
length     <dbl> 500, 170, 480, 284, 30, 500, 270, 476, 395, 80, 500, 500, 500, 110, 500, 363, 254, 113, 500, 200, 27, 583, 5…
age        <dbl> 6.120548, 5.967123, 8.824658, 9.824658, 3.808219, 3.095890, 6.797260, 2.816438, 4.975342, 18.904110, 14.1315…
mat_source <chr> "ark", "bg", "brnl", "brnl", "bg", "brnl", "brnl", "ark", "brnl", "ark", "brnl", "ark", "ark", "brnl", "brnl"…
con_num    <dbl> 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, …

#Check unique values
unique(Inventory$mat_source)
[1] "ark"   "bg"    "brnl"  "arl"   "arkm"  "black"

Inventory %>% group_by(mat_source) %>%
summarise(Count = n())
A tibble: 6 × 2
mat_source Count
# #   <chr>      <int>
1 ark         1394
2 arkm           6
3 arl            1
4 bg          1361
5 black          4
6 brnl        2094
```

I am needing to replace "arkm" and "arl" with "ark", and also "black" with "bg".

I have tried the following without any success

```r
mutate(Inventory, mat_source = fct_recode(mat_source, "arl" = "ark"))

Inventory$mat_source <- ifelse(Inventory$mat_source  == "arl", "alk", Inventory$mat_source) Inventory <- Inventory %>% mutate(mat_source = factor(mat_source, levels = mat_source))
```

It is only fixing 11/4860 values but necessary to have correct data; please advise how to better handle this.

Comment: Using the dplyr library, one option is to use the `case_when()` function (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) to make the required changes, e.g. `updated_inventory <- mutate(Inventory, case_when(mat_source == "arkm" ~ "ark", mat_source == "arl" ~ "ark", mat_source == "black" ~ "bg", TRUE ~ mat_source)); glimpse(updated_inventory)` (untested)

Answer (score 0):

When multiple works need to be edited or replaced using `stringr::str_replace_all()` using a named vector in the form `c("pattern" = "replacement")` is an option.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# sample data frame
df1 <- data.frame(txt = c("arkm", "arl", "black", "brnl", "bg", "ark"))

# named vector with text pattern and their replacement 
corrections <- 
  c("arkm" = "ark",
    "arl" =  "ark",
    "black" = "bg")

# and finally the dplyr mutate to make the changes
df1 |> 
  mutate(txt_new = str_replace_all(txt, corrections))

#>     txt txt_new
#> 1  arkm     ark
#> 2   arl     ark
#> 3 black      bg
#> 4  brnl    brnl
#> 5    bg      bg
#> 6   ark     ark
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>